# JBoss - how programatically check values from standalone.xml?

Tags: properties, jboss, bind

Does anyone know how to check in runtime from code if configuration has defined e.g. 'any-address' tag?

```
...
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
...
```

For "jboss.bind.address" i can get system property - but what in "any-address" case?

Comment: What version of JBoss AS? There is a resource that defines what the address is set to, just depends on what the version of AS is.

Comment: I'm working with jboss 7.1

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run a [co-located management client](http://management-platform.blogspot.ch/2012/07/co-located-management-client-for.html) from within your application.